# Element Present in One group must present with other too

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Seeking help on this complicated scenario.

I have three table called as `Interchange`, `Driver` and `Application`

ALL SKU from APPLICATION table which are present in Interchange table with Checks as 'REP'  and available with column called as 'Baseline' and Correspondance NewSKU which  present  with Newline present In Driver Table

Tables:-

```
DECLARE @Interchange TABLE
(
SKU VARCHAR (50),
CHECKS VARCHAR (50),
NewSKU VARCHAR (50)
)


INSERT @Interchange
SELECT 'AEM41-1408DS',  'Bridgestone',  '41-1408DS' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AEM41-1408DS',  'REP',  'AEM21-203DK'


DECLARE @Driver TABLE
(
BaseLine VARCHAR (50),
NewLine VARCHAR (50)
)



INSERT @Driver

SELECT 'Cold Air Intake',   'Air Filter%'


DECLARE @APPLICATION TABLE
(   
SKU VARCHAR (50),
line VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @APPLICATION


SELECT 'AEM41-1408DS',  'Cold Air Intake' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AEM41-1408DS',  'Cold Air Intake' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AEM41-1408DS',  'Cold Air Intake' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AEM41-1408DS',  'Cold Air Intake' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AEM21-203DK',   'Air Filter High'
```

Can any one please suggest t-sql query for this complicated scenario?

Comment: Showing just sample data and desired output in tabular format would have been much helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the whole thing starting with "ALL SKU ". I read it thrice and got lost in the middle ... Can't you simplify your question? We're all short in time.

Comment: The Output need to be fetched from Application table, AND 

driver table is used to check line for SKU and NewSKU

WE NEED to check SKU (from Interchange table and base line from driver) and correspondance NewSKU (from Interchange table and Newline from driver table)
both should be present in Application Table Than it should appear in Output

where checks should be REP

Comment: Same class as Lewis? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944473/count-vales-in-db)

Comment: If SKUs  with both baseline and newline present in application table
and CHECKS for those SKU is 'REP' In Interchange table.

if SKU available with only baseline or available with only newline should not appear in Output

Comment: @jarlh: is it possible to have T-SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand with you comments, I have written below query for you, if it is not fulfill your requirement, then please share sample output.

```
select A.* from @APPLICATION  A
where exists (select sku from @Interchange where A.SKU = SKU)
AND EXISTS (SELECT baseLine from  @Driver where BaseLine = A.line)
```