# count vales in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking to upload a `cvs` into a db and then find how many times an instance of data appears to create a pick list.

I upload a cvs in to the db leaving me with

SKU and QUANTITY

I use to get the data from the db but I cant seam to find a way to group that data so their is only 1 sku for each item and a number of ordered items.

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from pickcount");
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fetch['sku']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fetch['quan']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>  

</table>
```

Comment: What dbms (*MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle etc...*) are you using? Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: im useing php and mysql im at the moment this will output 

sku-2 2
sku-1 1
sku-1  2
sku-2 1

im looking to group that output to

sku-2 4
sku-1 2

Comment: Same class as shan? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944096/element-present-in-one-group-must-present-with-other-too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT sku, SUM(quan) AS Sum_Of_Quan FROM   pickcount GROUP BY sku");
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fetch['sku']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fetch['Sum_Of_Quan']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>  
</table>
```

Try to replace your table structure with above structure and check the result

Comment: $fetch['quan'] will probably throw an exception :)

Comment: now without code even I cannot test. let him test it. you can be right @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi

Comment: I was trying to suggest you change $fetch['quan'] to $fetch['Sum_Of_Quan']

Comment: my edit window was taking too much time. so btw thanks.

Comment: Actually it was my implantation of the code that killed it this is working fantastic! knew it would be something stupid always is thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your sql query to:

```
select sku, sum(quan) as sum_quan
from pickcount
group by sku
```

PS - you'll have to change

```
 php echo $fetch['quan'];
```

to

```
 php echo $fetch['sum_quan'];
```